# Visually suggestive way to present a finite group

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, visualization

When studying about groups, we can often grasp the structure of a small group "internally". For instance, we can "see" that $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ as a three-fold symmetric shape;more complicated examples include perceiving the difference in structure of $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2=K_4$ intuitively.

So the question is:

> Is there a graphical way to convey the structural information of small groups intuitively?

I realize that it is sort of vague, but any answer is appreciated. You can just focus on specific examples of groups, but a general method would be great. Thanks.

Comment: There's Cayley graphs, but I've never found them all that illuminating.

Comment: @Randall I agree with that.

Comment: Letting a group act faithfully on a (finite) set (perhaps with some structure) often gives a clarifying perspective. Good examples are provided by the cyclic and dihedral groups acting on a regular polygon; the Platonic solids and their groups of simmetries; representations of groups as matrix groups.